# Prevent onblur code to execute if clicked on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onblur

By the following code I wish to "DO SOMETHING" on "ONBLUR" of element id="eg1" only if the onblur event was not caused due to "ONCLICK" on the submit button.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
     $('#eg1').blur(function() {
      if(!($("#SubmitBut").click())) {
             //do something
      }
     });
    });
```

For Eg : if the user changes value of the “eg1” text field and clicks on the next text field then the DO SOMETHING code must run, but in case the user changes value of the the “eg1” field and then clicks on the SUBMIT button, then the DO SOMETHING code must not run.

Is it the correct way to do so ??
Please guide.

Comment: you cant do like this. u cant capture two events at a time.

Comment: @Ravi : please help me with the correct way to accomplish the task

Comment: @PalakTaneja: Please view the fiddle I have created. I have updated my previous answer after reading the question carefully.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`blur` event of an element triggers before `click` event of another. So one way is to use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to toggle a flag, because `mousedown` event of one element triggers before `blur` event of another one.

```
$("#eg1").on("blur", function(e){
  if($("#submit").data("mouseDown") != true){
      alert("DO SOMETHING");
  }
});

$("#submit").on("mousedown", function(e){
    $("#submit").data("mouseDown", true);
  });

$("#submit").on("mouseup", function(e){
    $("#submit").data("mouseDown", false);
  });
```

Comment: @Diode please tell will that work in mobile also? as mobile functionalities are tap or click functionalities so.

Comment: are you using jQuery mobile ?

Answer (score 3):

Answering this old question (since it came up for me first in Google). There was a more elegant solution described in [this other S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630197/1302484), which is to just call event.preventDefault() in the onMouseDown handler.

So in modern component frameworks:

```
<button onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()} /button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

`$('input[type="submit"]').mousedown(test);`

Have a look at this fiddle [JSFiddle to address your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/xYujL/2/). Use the console to view the events triggered and suppressed after specific actions are performed.

You should suppress the event handler that is bound to the text when `click` or `submit` is performed.

Comment: This is not something that i am looking for...,probably you dint get my problem correctly...Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
A trick -

 $(document).ready(function() {  
var flag = false;
     $('#eg1').blur(function() {
flag = true;
      if(!($("#SubmitBut").click())) {
if(flag) 
   return false;            
 //do something
      }
     });
    });
```

Comment: this does the same thing, captures 2 events at the same time which is not permitted.