# onBlur and onFocus in React to create a menu that appears/disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am learning react and am building a little electronic store. I have this tab called "View Store". When a user clicks on it, I want a little "peek-a-boo" column to appear and let the user view some text or pictures. When a user clicks anywhere else, I want this column to disappear.

What I do is define a state prop called "peekaboo". When a user clicks on my div, I set peekaboo to true. When a user blurs out, I set peekaboo to false, but what happens is that onClick works, but onBlur does not (store button dissappears but it never reappears when I am out of focus).

```
class ProductPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.peekClick = this.peekClick.bind(this);
    this.peekHide = this.peekHide.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      peekaboo: false
    };
  }

  peekClick = () => {
    this.setState({peekaboo: true});}

  peekHide = () => {
    this.setState({peekaboo: false});}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ProductPage">
        <div className="ProductPage-Left">
        {/* PROBLEM IS HERE */}
            <div className="leftViewTab" onBlur={this.peekHide}>
              {this.state.peekaboo ? (null) :
                (<div className="leftViewText" onClick={this.peekClick}>
                    View Store
              </div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
```

I looked at these stackoverflow posts for ideas:
[onclick() and onblur() ordering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769005/onclick-and-onblur-ordering-issue)

I also found the onBlur idea on another question, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: I don't believe you can blur a div (since the opposite of blur is focus, not click) - try detecting a click elsewhere on the page? or on `<body>` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onBlur` only applies to elements that can be focused (e.g., elements that would be selected while pressing `tab`).  That event will never fire.

Depending on your intended behavior, you might want to explore `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.