# jQuery: Prevent focus loss of input when clicking on specific element

Tags: jquery

I have an input that contains a custom drop down menu. When you click on a menu item it should set the value of the input to the text of the item. I also want the menu to hide when the input loses focus. This has created a problem, where clicking a menu item makes the input lose focus and hide the menu before the click event for the menu item can be run. How do I fix this?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#inputMenu li', function (e) {
    $('#input').val($(this).text());
    $('#inputMenu').removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
});
  
$('#input').on('focusout',function(e) {
    $('#inputMenu').removeClass('active');
});
 
$('#input').on('input',function(e) {
    $('#inputMenu').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#inputMenu {
  display: none;
}

#inputMenu.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="type something">
<ul id="inputMenu">
  <li>Click me to set text 1</li>
  <li>Click me to set text 2</li>
  <li>Click me to set text 3</li>
  <li>Click me to set text 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of HTML and convert your code to a runnable snippet?

Comment: Snippet has been added.

Comment: Since you’ve already got a good answer, I won’t add another. Just a quick note though: to me as a user, using `focus` and `blur` would be more intuitive than `input` and `focusout`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is caused by the order of events. There is a trick you can use, replace `click` event with `mousedown` which is fired before `focusout`.

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '#inputMenu li', function (e) {
    $('#input').val($(this).text());
    $('#inputMenu').removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
});
  
$('#input').on('focusout',function(e) {
    $('#inputMenu').removeClass('active');
});
 
$('#input').on('input',function(e) {
    $('#inputMenu').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#inputMenu {
  display: none;
}

#inputMenu.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="type something">
<ul id="inputMenu">
  <li>Click me to set text 1</li>
  <li>Click me to set text 2</li>
  <li>Click me to set text 3</li>
  <li>Click me to set text 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Credits:**

This answer was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28963938/6358255)

Comment: 'click' -> 'mousedown', you saved my day ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="inputMenu">
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 2</li>
        <li>test 3</li>
        <li>test 4</li>
        <li>test 5</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="input">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '#inputMenu li', function (e) {
            $('#input').val($(this).text()).focus();
        });
        $('#input').on('focusout',function(e) {
            let curElem = this;
            $('#inputMenu li:visible').each(function(){
                if($(curElem).val() == $(this).text())
                    $(this).hide()
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```