# Material UI autocomplete popper custom closes on click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a button to the Material UI autocomplete paper by overriding the `PaperComponent` prop and added a button at the button of the paper, but clicking on the button automatically closes the autocomplete search results

How can i prevent the autocomplete search results Paper from closing on click

Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-mxjyi

UPDATE: I didn't notice that the sandbox did not save, now you can see the issue

Comment: I don't see where the problem is...

Comment: When you click the button it autocomplete results closes automatically without alerting

Comment: @MarioVernari I edited the sandbox, you can now see the issue https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-mxjyi

Comment: I see now, but I have no clues at the moment...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the `onBlur` which occurs before your `onClick`. Material UI offers to ignore the blur behaviour on `debug` mode but that happens only if you have a value inside your `Autocomplete`.

The workaround is to use `onMouseDown` instead of `onClick`

Based on your Codesanbox please change the `onClick` event to `onMouseDown` event in your `<button>` component

```js
<button
   style={{ margin: "10px", padding: "5px" }}
   onMouseDown={() => alert("clicked")}
>
```

The problem, which is not Material-UI related, was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769005/onclick-and-onblur-ordering-issue) also

Answer (score 2):

using `onMouseDown` on the button is not the proper solution here as the user is expecting a different behavior. You can call `preventDefault` on the paper component to prevent it from closing.

```js
<Autocomplete
  //other props...
  PaperComponent={(props) => (
    <Paper onMouseDown={event => event.preventDefault()}>
      <Button>Click</Button>
    </Paper>
  )}
/>
```