# Material UI autocomplete closes on click when it was supposed to display a popover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, blur

I am trying to add a button to the Material UI autocomplete throgh the renderOption prop and added a button at each row which was supposed to display a PopOver component, but clicking on the button automatically closes the autocomplete search results

How can I prevent the autocomplete search results from closing on click

Here is a sandbox with my code: [https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rgb-z88y10](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rgb-z88y10?file=/demo.tsx:242-254)

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864259/material-ui-autocomplete-popper-custom-closes-on-click) other similar issue, but in my case I am trying to set thr `renderOption` prop and not the `PaperComponent`
But unfortunatelly in my case it wasn´t enough to just set the function to run on the onMouseDown event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a controlled `Autocomplete` by using the `open` prop on the component. The `onClose` gives you various reasons why the Popover wants to close, you can find them all in the [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/).

We check if the reason is **selectOption** if it is we do nothing and return out. If it is not we set `isOpen` to false to close the Popover

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

return (
  <Autocomplete
    renderOption={(props, label) => (
      <PopOver
        {...props}
        id={props.id}
        label={label.label}
        message={label.label}
      />
    )}
    id="combo-box-demo"
    open={isOpen}
    onOpen={() => setIsOpen(true)}
    onClose={(e, reason) => {
      if (reason === "selectOption") return;
      setIsOpen(false);
    }}
    options={top100Films}
    sx={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
  />
);
```