# Javascript build drop down menu not work in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in  web apps development and new in Javascript.  I have a hover drop down menu.  The menu is build from Javascript and CSS.  It's work fine in desktop browser but it's not work in mobile browser.  When user click the top level menu, nothing drop down show in mobile broswer.  Anything in CSS going wrong

here is the aspx

```
 <div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu" runat="server">
                <ul class="menu" id="AMenu" runat="server" visible="true">                         
                    <li class="active" runat="server" id="MenuSummary">
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="parent" NavigateUrl="#"> 
   <span>Summary Report</span></asp:HyperLink>
                         <ul>
                            <li class="active" runat="server" id="Summary"><a href="~/Summary.aspx" class="parent" runat="server"><span>Summary Report</span></a> </li>
                            <li class="active" runat="server" id="SummarySR"><a href="~/View.aspx" class="parent" runat="server"><span>View</span></a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
              </ul>
```

here is the javascript

```
var ddsmoothmenu = {

arrowimages: { down: ['downarrowclass', '../images/down.gif', 23], right: ['rightarrowclass', '../images/right1.gif'] },
transition: { overtime: 200, outtime: 200 }, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds
shadow: { enable: true, offsetx: 5, offsety: 5 }, //enable shadow?
showhidedelay: { showdelay: 50, hidedelay: 100 }, //set delay in milliseconds before sub menus appear and disappear, respectively

///////Stop configuring beyond here///////////////////////////

detectwebkit: navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("applewebkit") != -1, //detect WebKit browsers (Safari, Chrome etc)
detectie6: document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
css3support: window.msPerformance || (!document.all && document.querySelector), //detect browsers that support CSS3 box shadows (ie9+ or FF3.5+, Safari3+, Chrome etc)
ismobile: navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i) != null, //boolean check for popular mobile browsers

getajaxmenu: function ($, setting) { //function to fetch external page containing the panel DIVs
    var $menucontainer = $('#' + setting.contentsource[0]) //reference empty div on page that will hold menu
    $menucontainer.html("Loading Menu...")
    $.ajax({
        url: setting.contentsource[1], //path to external menu file
        async: true,
        error: function (ajaxrequest) {
            $menucontainer.html('Error fetching content. Server Response: ' + ajaxrequest.responseText)
        },
        success: function (content) {
            $menucontainer.html(content)
            ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting)
        }
    })
},


buildmenu: function ($, setting) {
    var smoothmenu = ddsmoothmenu
    var $mainmenu = $("#" + setting.mainmenuid + ">ul") //reference main menu UL
    $mainmenu.parent().get(0).className = setting.classname || "ddsmoothmenu"
    var $headers = $mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
    $headers.hover(

    function (e) {
        if (!$(this).children('a:eq(0)').hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).children('a:eq(0)').addClass('selected');
        }
    },
    function (e) {
        if ($(this).children('a:eq(0)').attr('rel') != "yes") {
            $(this).children('a:eq(0)').removeClass('selected')
        }
    }
)
    $headers.each(function (i) { //loop through each LI header
        var $curobj = $(this).css({ zIndex: 100 - i }) //reference current LI header
        var $subul = $(this).find('ul:eq(0)').css({ display: 'block' })
        $subul.data('timers', {})
        this._dimensions = { w: this.offsetWidth, h: this.offsetHeight, subulw: $subul.outerWidth(), subulh: $subul.outerHeight() }
        this.istopheader = $curobj.parents("ul").length == 1 ? true : false //is top level header?
        $subul.css({ top: this.istopheader && setting.orientation != 'v' ? this._dimensions.h + "px" : 0 })
        $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader ? { paddingRight: smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[2]} : {}).append( //add arrow images
        '<img src="' + (this.istopheader && setting.orientation != 'v' ? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[1] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[1])
        + '" class="' + (this.istopheader && setting.orientation != 'v' ? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[0] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[0])
        + '" style="border:0;" />'
    )
        if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support) { //if shadows enabled and browser doesn't support CSS3 box shadows
            this._shadowoffset = { x: (this.istopheader ? $subul.offset().left + smoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : this._dimensions.w), y: (this.istopheader ? $subul.offset().top + smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : $curobj.position().top)} //store this shadow's offsets
            if (this.istopheader)
                $parentshadow = $(document.body)
            else {
                var $parentLi = $curobj.parents("li:eq(0)")
                $parentshadow = $parentLi.get(0).$shadow
            }
            this.$shadow = $('<div class="ddshadow' + (this.istopheader ? ' toplevelshadow' : '') + '"></div>').prependTo($parentshadow).css({ left: this._shadowoffset.x + 'px', top: this._shadowoffset.y + 'px' })  //insert shadow DIV and set it to parent node for the next shadow div
        }
        $curobj.hover(
        function (e) {
            var $targetul = $subul //reference UL to reveal
            var header = $curobj.get(0) //reference header LI as DOM object
            clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').hidetimer)
            $targetul.data('timers').showtimer = setTimeout(function () {
                header._offsets = { left: $curobj.offset().left, top: $curobj.offset().top }
                var menuleft = header.istopheader && setting.orientation != 'v' ? 0 : header._dimensions.w
                menuleft = (header._offsets.left + menuleft + header._dimensions.subulw > $(window).width()) ? (header.istopheader && setting.orientation != 'v' ? -header._dimensions.subulw + header._dimensions.w : -header._dimensions.w) : menuleft //calculate this sub menu's offsets from its parent
                if ($targetul.queue().length <= 1) { //if 1 or less queued animations
                    $targetul.css({ left: menuleft + "px", width: header._dimensions.subulw + 'px' }).animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
                    if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support) {
                        var shadowleft = header.istopheader ? $targetul.offset().left + ddsmoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : menuleft
                        var shadowtop = header.istopheader ? $targetul.offset().top + smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : header._shadowoffset.y
                        if (!header.istopheader && ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit) { //in WebKit browsers, restore shadow's opacity to full
                            header.$shadow.css({ opacity: 1 })
                        }
                        header.$shadow.css({ overflow: '', width: header._dimensions.subulw + 'px', left: shadowleft + 'px', top: shadowtop + 'px' }).animate({ height: header._dimensions.subulh + 'px' }, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
                    }
                }
            }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.showdelay)
        },
        function (e) {
            var $targetul = $subul
            var header = $curobj.get(0)
            clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').showtimer)
            $targetul.data('timers').hidetimer = setTimeout(function () {
                $targetul.animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
                if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support) {
                    if (ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit) { //in WebKit browsers, set first child shadow's opacity to 0, as "overflow:hidden" doesn't work in them
                        header.$shadow.children('div:eq(0)').css({ opacity: 0 })
                    }
                    header.$shadow.css({ overflow: 'hidden' }).animate({ height: 0 }, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
                }
            }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.hidedelay)
        }
    ) //end hover
    }) //end $headers.each()
    if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && smoothmenu.css3support) { //if shadows enabled and browser supports CSS3 shadows
        var $toplevelul = $('#' + setting.mainmenuid + ' ul li ul')
        var css3shadow = parseInt(smoothmenu.shadow.offsetx) + "px " + parseInt(smoothmenu.shadow.offsety) + "px 5px #aaa" //construct CSS3 box-shadow value
        var shadowprop = ["boxShadow", "MozBoxShadow", "WebkitBoxShadow", "MsBoxShadow"] //possible vendor specific CSS3 shadow properties
        for (var i = 0; i < shadowprop.length; i++) {
            $toplevelul.css(shadowprop[i], css3shadow)
        }
    }
    $mainmenu.find("ul").css({ display: 'none', visibility: 'visible' })
},

init: function (setting) {
    if (typeof setting.customtheme == "object" && setting.customtheme.length == 2) { //override default menu colors (default/hover) with custom set?
        var mainmenuid = '#' + setting.mainmenuid
        var mainselector = (setting.orientation == "v") ? mainmenuid : mainmenuid + ', ' + mainmenuid
        document.write('<style type="text/css">\n'
        + mainselector + ' ul li a {background:' + setting.customtheme[0] + ';}\n'
        + mainmenuid + ' ul li a:hover {background:' + setting.customtheme[1] + ';}\n'
    + '</style>')
    }
    this.shadow.enable = (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest) ? false : this.shadow.enable //in IE6, always disable shadow
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //ajax menu?
        if (typeof setting.contentsource == "object") { //if external ajax menu
            ddsmoothmenu.getajaxmenu($, setting)
        }
        else { //else if markup menu
            ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting)
        }
    })
}

} //end ddsmoothmenu variable
```

Here is the CSS

```
.ddsmoothmenu{
    font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url("../images/sub-head-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #01916d; 
    /*background of menu bar (default state)*/
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
  }

 .ddsmoothmenu ul{
  z-index:100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left:10px;
}

 /*Top level list items*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li{
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}

 /*Top level menu link items style*/
 .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{
display: block;
 /*background: #414141;*/ /*background of menu items (default state)*/
 color: white;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 border-right: 1px solid #01916d;
 color: #2d2b2b;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul ul li a{
 background: #65d9b2;
}

 .ddsmoothmenu ul ul li a:hover{
  background: #01916d;
```

}

```
* html .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack to get sub menu links to behave correctly*/
display: inline-block;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a:link, .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:visited{
color: white;
```

}

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a.selected{ /*CSS class that's dynamically added to the currently active 
menu items' LI A element*/
  background: #65d9b2; 
  color: white;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover{
  background: #65d9b2; /*background of menu items during onmouseover (hover state)*/
 color: white;
}

/*1st sub level menu*/
  .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none; /*collapse all sub menus to begin with*/
  visibility: hidden;
  width:179px !important;
  margin-left:0px;
}

    /*Sub level menu list items (undo style from Top level List Items)*/
   .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
  display: list-item;
  float: none;
  margin-left:0px;

}

/*All subsequent sub menu levels vertical offset after 1st level sub menu */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul{
top: 0;
}

/* Sub level menu links style */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a{
 font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 width: 163px; /*width of sub menus*/
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
 margin: 0;
 border-top: 1px dotted #a6ffe9;
 border-right:none;
}
 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li:last-child a{border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}

 /* Holly Hack for IE \*/
 * html .ddsmoothmenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/


 /* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  ######### */

.downarrowclass {
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 7px;
}

.rightarrowclass {
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 5px;
}

/* ######### CSS for shadow added to sub menus  ######### */

.ddshadow{ /*shadow for NON CSS3 capable browsers*/
  position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 background: silver;
}

.toplevelshadow{ /*shadow opacity for NON CSS3 capable browsers. Doesn't work in IE*/
 opacity: 0.8;
}


.ddsmoothmenu-v ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 170px; /* Main Menu Item widths */
 list-style-type: none;
 font: bold 11px Verdana;
}

.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li{
 position: relative;
}

/* Top level menu links style */
 .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a{
   display: block;
   overflow: auto; /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 6px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #778;
   border-right: 1px solid #778;
  }

 .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:link, .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:visited, .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li 
 a:active{
 background: #414141; /*background of menu items (default state)*/
 color: white;
}


 .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a.selected{ /*CSS class that's dynamically added to the currently 
 active menu items' LI A element*/
background: black; 
color: white;
}

.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:hover{
 background: black; /*background of menu items during onmouseover (hover state)*/
 color: white;
}

 /*Sub level menu items */
 .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li ul{
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px; /*Sub Menu Items width */
  top: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  visibility: hidden; /*it's here i should make change to true and important */
 }


 /* Holly Hack for IE \*/
 * html .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li { float: left; height: 1%; }
 * html .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a { height: 1%; }
 /* End */
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said I assume your dropdown-functionality is based on "hover"?

If that is in fact so, there is an easy explanation:

when using touch devices there is no "hover" functionality. If you want your app to be used on touch devices you need to either avoid using hover altogether or implement a touch-compatible alternative for each hover functionality you have. (and even disregarding touch devices: hover still doesn't consider mousless use (using tab to navigate)) - so having major functionality only accesible by hover is a major accesabilty deficit. (so maybe don't do it)

For dropdows (or form elements in general) you could use focus events instead of hover (those work for desktop (tab and mouse) and mobile/touch (For further help: In this answer you can see how you could implement a dropdown with the use of focus events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73922116/19529102)

Comment: it's means I need to replace the hover in the javascript and CSS to focus/active.   $curobj.hover( -->  $curobj.focus(     , .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover{ --> .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:focus{