# How to click on anchor tags inside React dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

I have a dropdown & I need to use this dropdown multiple places in same page.

My issue: after open any dropdown I'm not able to click on dropdown links. When I'm trying to click then dropdown is disappearing.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdownoutsideissue-tx2lqr?file=/src/Dropdown.tsx)

Comment: Hi Rohit. Could you edit this question to bring the relevant code into the question? You can leave the code sandbox link at the end, but the code (or the most important piece) needs to be here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [onclick() and onblur() ordering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769005/onclick-and-onblur-ordering-issue/57630197#57630197)

Add the `onMouseDown` event on the `a` component and call `e.preventDefault()`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Dropdown = () => {
    const [actionIsOpen, setActionIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const actionList = [
        { id: '1', name: 'One' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Two' },
        { id: '3', name: 'Three' },
        { id: '4', name: 'Four' },
    ];

    const handleActionClick = () => {
        setActionIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="tw-relative">
                <span onClick={handleActionClick} onBlur={() => setActionIsOpen(false)} className="tw-cursor-pointer">
                    <button>Dropdown Click</button>
                </span>
                {actionIsOpen && (
                    <div className="shadow tw-w-48 tw-absolute tw-top-2 tw-z-50 tw-left-4 tw-bg-white tw-pt-2">
                        {actionList.map((val: any) => (
                            <div
                                key={val.id}
                                className="tw-bg-white-100 hover:tw-bg-violet-100 hover:tw-text-violet-900 tw-cursor-pointer hover:tw-font-bold py-2 px-3 tw-text-gray-600">
                                <a href="#" onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                                    {val.name}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76629821-forked-gzjy4y?file=/src/Dropdown.tsx)