# Collapse div when clicked beyond input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have a search field on my website, which is implemented using HTML input and regular div.

Functionality for the user: The user can click on the input field -> start entering characters -> below this field a div with suggested options will open -> by clicking on one of the proposed options, this option will appear in the input field

```
export function View() {
  const { data: nodes } = useNodes();

  const itemsDisplay = useMemo(() => nodes, [nodes]);

  const itemsAfterSearch = itemsDisplay.filter((node_) => {
    if (nodeQuery === '' || nodeQuery === node_.title) {
      return '';
    }
    if (node_.title.includes(nodeQuery)) {
      return node;
    }
    return '';
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={(event) => setNodeQuery(event.target.value)}
        value={nodeQuery}
      />
      {itemsAfterSearch.length ? (
        <>
          {itemsAfterSearch.map((node_) => (
            <button
              key={node_.id}
              onClick={() => {
                setNodeQuery(node_.title);
                setNode(node_);
              }}
            >
              <div>{node_.title}</div>
            </button>
          ))}
        </>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is that if you click the cursor outside the input field, the div remains expanded. Please tell me how to collapse a div when the cursor clicks outside the input?

Comment: Would a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) perhaps work better? Then you wouldn't have to manually open or collapse the div.

Comment: Perhaps this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`onBlur`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-onblur-event/) event. You can then set a boolean or css class name when the `<input />` gains or loses focus.

In this example, I used a boolean and changed the div's className based on isExpanded boolean

```
...
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = React.useState(false)

return (
<div>
  <input
    onChange={(event) => setNodeQuery(event.target.value)}
    value={nodeQuery}
    onFocus={() => setIsExpanded(true);}
    onBlur={() => setIsExpanded(false);}
  />
  {itemsAfterSearch.length ? (
    <>
      ...
      <div className={`dropdown-style ${isExpanded ? "" : "hide"}` >
      {node_.title}</div>
      ...
   </>
  ) : (
  ""
  )}
</div>
)

// style.css
.dropdown-style {
  ...
}
.hide {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Note:** You can use `onClick` instead of `onFocus` if you would like

Comment: Where do you define isExpanded ? Could you adapt your answer with my code?

Comment: I apologize. I haven't used React for a few years and I forgot that they moved away from state components and I have never used the useMemo or useNodes hooks. You could use Vanilla JS to target the input tag and see if it has focus but I know that React frowns on interacting directly with the DOM. Anyway, I added the [useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) Hook to my answer, which should allow you to use a variable throughout this component.

Comment: Yes, this is a pretty good solution. But for some reason, when I click on any element {node_.title} to select the one I need, it is not selected

Comment: It sounds like you might need to change your <button> tag's onClick event to the onFocus event. You can also try adding the onMouseDown event to the button with the onClick event and have the onMouseDown event to trigger event.preventDefault(). You can see the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769005/onclick-and-onblur-ordering-issue